# send parameter in url (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, angular7

Want to send parameter in url in angular 7, so that the url should look like return **example.com/search/users?q=tom.**

I am using the following syntax in my service .

```
 public searchUsers(obj):any{
        return this._http.get('example.com/search/users?q=', obj)
    }
```

I want the url to be look like **`example.com/search/users?q=`**

Comment: Hello yash. I have read your question and I found your term 'send parameter in URL' very disturbing. Can you give more explanations. What do you want ? Loading a page with parameter for a specific URL ? Asking some information from another site to retrieve user information ? Why 'TOM' is in your text and why TOM is not more in your code ? Can you try to give us more information ? Thanks

Comment: he is trying to make an API call with query params in url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it using [HttpParam](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams).

```
const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('q', 'value here')
        .set('another_param', 'value_here');
return this.httpClient.get('example.com/search/users', { params })
```

Answer (score 0):

Addon to the correct answer:

If you are wondering why no parameters get passed, there is a key hint in the referenced HttpParams docs

> This class is immutable - all mutation operations return a new
>   instance.

That means this will work:

```
let params = new HttpParams();
if ( limit ) {
  params.set('limit', String(limit));
}
params.set('search', keyword);
```

If you want to append HttpParams conditionally, use a variation of this instead:

```
let params = new HttpParams();
if ( limit ) {
  params = params.set('limit', String(limit));
}
params = params.set('search', keyword);
```

Learned this the hard way. Hope this helps any other TS beginners to save a bit of confusion...